# Probability of drawing a 4 and 5 in a lottery

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider a lottery where a winning number is selected from a bowl of 100 balls where 10 balls are labeled with each unique digit (ten 0's, ten 1's, ten 2's and so on), and 4 balls are still drawn. Given that the first ball drawn is a 1, what is the probability that the winning combination contains a 5 and 4?
Also note that each number can only be used at most once.

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, the rules aren't really clear.  When you say that "each number can only be used once" do yoiu mean that $\{1,1,1,1\}$  or $\{1,2,2,1\}$ aren]t allowed?  If that's the case, why on earth do they put duplicates in?

Comment: Also, when you say "4 balls are still drawn", do you mean "5 balls are drawn overall"?

Comment: I think its supposed to be 4 draws in total, but the first ball is a "1," and I'm assuming that once you draw a number then all of that number is removed from the bowl

Comment: If that's the case, then you can ignore all the duplicates and just assume you started with $10$ balls with distinct numbers on them.  Having drawn the $1$ you are now drawing three numbers without replacement from $\{0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. Given all that, can you finish?

Comment: yea, but my friends and I have gotten vastly different answers, none of which are the one that the teacher provided, which was ~4%

Comment: I ended up with 7choose1/9choose3, but that comes out to ~8.3%

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this probability tree is correct now (although I'm in a rush, so not certain). You should work out the probabilities yourself...

[image]

Comment: Is it wrong because in the next to the bottom branch it is impossible to end up with both a $4$ and a $5$?

Comment: I tried doing that too and came out with~8.0%, which was different from both my answer and the teacher's answer. Thanks though

Comment: I think it's wrong because this model would take two 4s or two 5s as correct

Comment: OK, edited.....

Comment: Okay, thanks. It comes out to what I had, but I'm still not sure how my teacher got~4%

Comment: Occasionally, teachers are wrong.